# I can't get proper uint32 number in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, uint

i am trying to convert a long number to unit in JavaScript, but the result i got it different from the one i already have in c#.

c#:

```
var tt=431430059159441001;
var t=(UInt32)tt;//1570754153
```

js:

```
var arr =new Uint32Array(1);
arr[0]=431430059159441001;//1570754176
```

so could any body explain why there is difference.

Comment: Your code gives `CS0221 Constant value '431430059159441001' cannot be converted to a 'uint' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)`. Please update your question and add details what actually you are doing with working examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your number literal is rather a 64 bit integer, and that cannot be represented in JavaScripts regular [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) type. The number type is a 64-bit precision floating point number, which [can only represent integer values up to around `2**53`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/5108418). So I would recommend to just not use such a huge number literal.

A recent development in the JavaScript world is [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s. If you can afford to use them, then your code is easy to fix:

```js
var t = Number(BigInt.asUintN(32, 431430059159441001n));
console.log(t); // 1570754153
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not about uints, but about floats. JavaScript uses floating point numbers, and your number exceeds the maximum range of integers that can safely be represented:

```
console.log(431430059159441001)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `431430059159441001` to unsigned integer in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). Max Value of `UInt32` is `4294967295`. So the `var t=(UInt32)431430059159441001;` assignment gives Compiler error.

also `431430059159441001` is larger then max value of float number (javascript holds number with float format)